# Why Can't I update the values of the sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-update, addition

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

            if (btn66 == v) {
                ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
                value.put(DBhelper.Amount, txtBudget.getText().toString());
                value.put(DBhelper.Description, txr.getText().toString());

                if(DBhelper.Amount == null)
                {
                    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                    db.insert(DBhelper.TABLE2, null, value);
                    db.close();
                    clearfield();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Budget add Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fetchData2();
                    Intent i = new Intent(addbudget.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else{
                    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                    db.update(DBhelper.TABLE2, value, "_id "+"="+1, null);
                    db.close();

                    fetchData2();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Update Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clearfield();
                }
            }
        }
```

The above one is my code to add and update values to the sqlite database,after I include the Update method in my code,my add function is not working and my update function also not working.Is there any problem with my code,but I didn't get any error message.

This is my Database tables

```
     static final String C_ID = "_id";
        static final String Name = "name";
        static final String B_ID = "_id";

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE1+ "(" +C_ID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +Name+ " text unique not null)");

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE2+ "(" +B_ID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +Description+ " text,"
                        +Amount+ " text, FOREIGN KEY ("+Description+") REFERENCES "+TABLE1+"("+Name+"));");




   }
```

Comment: "not working" is a terrible explanation of what's going on. Are you getting an exception? What happens? Also include a language tag (java?). What is DBhelper? What libraries are you using?

Comment: It's  not giving any exception,when I click the button to add values,it's saying "Update Successfully",and  values  also not getting added to database. DBhelper is my Database class

Comment: Why are you checking `DBhelper.Amount == null`. isn't this a static string variable?

Comment: also can you post your table schema?

Comment: Sorry,actually I don't know whether that's the right way or not,I need to check  whether that particular column in my table is empty or not,and if it is empty ,I want to insert new values,otherwise i want to update that previous values

Comment: plz,see my updated answer for the table schema

Comment: That is definitely not the right way to do it. If you want to check if that particular table column is empty you need to make a `db.query` to check that and then do what you want to do.

Comment: can you also post the value of `C_ID ` and `B_ID` and other constants just to make sure that something stupid is not going on.

Comment: I again update my answer,please check it

Comment: Code would be easier to follow if your actual data wasn't static members on your database class (?), named with initial caps like class names. Basic readability is quite crucial when asking people to review code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this to check if a row with the given `name` is present in the `table1`:

```
public boolean checkIfRowPresent(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(DBhelper.TABLE1, null, DBHelper.NAME + "='" + name + "'", null, null, null,
                    null, null);
    boolean ret = false;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        ret = true; // There is a row present in table1 with the given name
    }
    db.close();

    return ret;

}
```

You should be calling it with this:

`checkIfRowPresent(txr.getText().toString())`

Let me know if it helps?

Comment: ok and how can I check the column is empty or not?can you briefly explain that plz

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,Thank you so much,your answer worked perfectly.

Comment: Nice. So can u upvote it and mark it as correct answer?

Comment: you can also mark it as correct answer by using the check mark below the the upvote.